# Angular HTML5 mode, router going to otherwise state on page reload

Tags: php, angularjs, .htaccess

I am trying to remove hash tag from my website. I have achieved it by following code.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

As well as added base URL in index file as well.

My issue is if i am on contct-us state after reloading entire page. i am redirecting to home state which is defined as otherwise state.

Configuration used are -

server -Appache
  database - mysql

I have added following code in .htaccess for rewriting rule as well -

```
     RewriteEngine On
     php_value post_max_size 120M 
    php_value upload_max_filesize 120M 
     php_value max_execution_time 90 



     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^54\.201\.153\.244$ [NC,OR]

     RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
     RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^adkarlo.com$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.adkarlo.com/$1 [R=301,L]

      #RewriteBase /html/
      ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
     RewriteRule ^ - [L]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Expected result - After reloading from state contact-us any page i want to go to same page.

Comment: shouldn't be any `#/` in path

Comment: @charlietfl - There is not any #/ in url but once, i refresh the page say from /about. It is redirecting me to /home state, which is state i have given in otherwise condition in stateProvider.

Comment: @charlietfl - I will be really thankful if you suggest me any solution. :)

Comment: He means your `RewriteRule` should point to `index.html`. See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: sorry @Phil i couldn't understand it. Will try this and let you know.

Comment: did you defined the contact-us route in angular js for loading template, please share your code, I think the url statement is going in default/ else section for template load. corrent me If wrong

Comment: @KuldeepPhPDeveloper - yes, i have defined it, for normal flow it it working. Flow is like home-->contact-us. it working fine if i go to home and then contact-us, but whenever i am trying to go directly to contact-us by entering url, i am ended up in home state.

Comment: try to comment in htaccess for ^(.*) as its going to find page related with #

Comment: i have changes code in .htaccess file as you suggested. still having same issue. Please have a look at question again i have edited question and code in .htaccess file as above

Comment: still not found any solution.... :)

Comment: Please check this URL - https://github.com/degr/forweb/blob/master/.htaccess . There you will be able to find some rewrite rules for redirecting from www.site.com to site.com and some other simple rewrite rules.

Comment: have you set unique urls for your angular routes?

Comment: yes @laney i have

Answer (score 3):

In order to support reloading of HTML5 mode route URLs, you need to implement server-side URL rewriting to direct non-file requests (that is, requests that aren't explicitly for an existing file) to your index file, typically `index.html`.

From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#server-side)

> Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application (e.g. index.html).

Your rewrite rule should not have any `#` in the destination URL. Instead, use this

```
RewriteEngine on

# Don't rewrite files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Source ~ https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Also, there's no need to set `RewriteBase`.

Comment: I have edited the question and code in .htaccess file still getting same issue. Please help me

Comment: @Chetan why do you have `index.php?/`? It should only be `index.php`

Comment: @Chetan please update your question to exactly reflect the current state of your code / configuration

Comment: Edited Question... still facing same issue.

Comment: @Chetan might be a silly question but have you enabled the `mod_rewrite` module? Can you share your route configuration?

Comment: i am still figuring out this .htaccess file, as i have only worked in front-end developement, it's really hard to figuring out terms in this file. :)

Comment: Can you please tell me what are you exactly want to know..??

Comment: @Chetan can you show your Angular code where you've set up your routes / states, including the `otherwise` part? Also, is the code in your question the entire `.htaccess` file, are you using Apache as your web server and is `index.php` the index file for your Angular application?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124766/discussion-between-chetan-and-phil).